# MFC ownerdrawn listbox scroll issue

Tags: mfc, listbox, ownerdrawn

I'm using [this logging listbox](http://www.flounder.com/logctl.htm), which happens to be an ownerdrawn listbox. I've noticed that when scrolling more than one line at a time, such as by using the mouse wheel or clicking on the scroll bar, it does it in a strange way.

Normally, when you scroll with the wheel, you can see the whole list going up smoothly by, say, 3 lines, and 3 new lines coming from the bottom. What I'm seeing with this control is as if a new page, starting 3 rows below, were coming from the top, which is quite confusing for the users.

I've also tried [this other listbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157250/Owner-Drawn-CListBox-Version-2) and it shows the same behaviour, so it seems something ownerdrawn-related.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This problem is also described here: https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/rrGhkTp3/scroll-wheel-problems-with-an-owner-draw-listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why you've been downvoted. It is a real problem. This is what I did to fix it. I have created my own CListBox derived class. There, I have created the handlers for WM_TIMER and WM_MOUSEWHEEL events.

In the handler for Mouse Wheel I have specified this:

```
#define TIMER_SCROLLING 8
BOOL CMyListBox::OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
{
  //return CListBox::OnMouseWheel(nFlags, zDelta, pt);

  // It turns out that a Listbox control created with the LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE  style does not 
  // handle the mouse wheel correctly. The scroll effect is very jumpy; so bad in fact, that if 
  // you want to use that style, it is advisable to intercept WM_MOUSEWHEEL to either disable it 
  // or write your own handler.
  // 'return TRUE' disables the scroll effect

#if 0
  // This will scroll one item at a time.
  // uncomment these lines if this is what you are after
  if(zDelta > 0)
  {
    SetTopIndex(GetTopIndex()-1);
  }
  else
  {
    SetTopIndex(GetTopIndex()+1);
  }

  return TRUE;
#endif

  // Will use timer to scroll the items smoothly. 
  // The scrolling is done in OnTimer event
  KillTimer(TIMER_SCROLLING);
  const int SCROLL_DELTA = 3; 
  if(zDelta > 0)
  {
    // scrolling up
    m_nStep -= SCROLL_DELTA;
  }
  else
  {
    // scrolling down
    m_nStep += SCROLL_DELTA;
  }
  SetTimer(TIMER_SCROLLING, 20, NULL);

  return TRUE;
}
```

And this is what I have coded in WM_TIMER handler:

```
void CMyListBox::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
  if(nIDEvent == TIMER_SCROLLING)
  {
    if(m_nStep < 0)
    {
      // scrolling up
      int nPos = GetTopIndex();
      if(nPos == 0)
      {
        m_nStep = 0;
        KillTimer(TIMER_SCROLLING);
      }
      else
      {
        SetTopIndex(nPos-1);
        m_nStep++;
      }
    }
    else if(m_nStep > 0)
    {
      // scrolling down
      int nPos = GetTopIndex();
      if(nPos == GetCount()-1)
      {
        m_nStep = 0;
        KillTimer(TIMER_SCROLLING);
      }
      else
      {
        SetTopIndex(nPos+1);
        m_nStep--;
      }
    }
    else
      KillTimer(TIMER_SCROLLING);
  }
  else
    CListBox::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Hope, this will help you and the others. I might need to consider putting it on Codeproject

Update:   `m_nStep` is defined as a private `int` member of CMyListBox class. Initialised as zero in the class constructor;

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I've added some code to take into account that the user can set the number of lines scrolled to something other than 3. So I've made SCROLL_DELTA non-const and I call SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES, 0, &SCROLL_DELTA, 0);

Comment: Also, I've added a function to compute the size of the visible page and set SCROLL_DELTA to that (minus 1) if the above call sets SCROLL_DELTA to WHEEL_PAGESCROLL.

Comment: BTW, as a small bonus I can provide you with a small piece of code that allows to "mouse-wheel" over controls without actually focusing on them first (many modern program do this, take e.g. MS Outlook). Just add these lines in your dialog's preTranslateMessage: `if(pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && GetCapture() == NULL)
  {
    // send Mouse wheel message to the mouse over control
    pMsg->hwnd = ::WindowFromPoint(pMsg->pt);
    pMsg->lParam = MAKELPARAM(pMsg->pt.x, pMsg->pt.y);
  }
  return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);`